# Ambiguous java error

Tags: java, debugging

```
public static int intersectionSizeMergeAndSort(studentList L1, studentList L2) {

  int intersectionSize = 0;
  int[] C = new int[L1.studentID.length+L2.studentID.length];
  for(int i = 0; i<L1.studentID.length; i++){
  C[i] = L1.studentID[i];
  }
  for(int i = 0; i<L2.studentID.length; i++){
  C[i+L1.studentID.length] = L2.studentID[i];
  }
  Arrays.sort(C);
  int pointer = 0;
  while(pointer<((L1.studentID.length)+(L2.studentId.length))){
    if(C[pointer] = C[pointer+1]){
    intersectionSize = intersectionSize + 1;
    pointer = pointer + 2;
    }
    else {
      pointer == pointer + 1;
  }
return intersectionSize;
  }
}
```

I have this algorithm I am writing for an assignment. Every time I compile my code, I get an error that I cannot understand in order to debug.
Error is as follows:

```
Error: /Users/nah/Desktop/studentList.java:137: operator < cannot be applied to int,<nulltype>
```

the error is pointing to the while loop statement

Comment: First, you must understand that we do not have line numbers to see. Secondly, it is enaugh to see only failed operation with operand declarations. We do not review code for application.

Comment: @cklab: The homework tag is deprecated.

Comment: What are the types of `L1.studentID` and `L2.studentID`?

Comment: they are an array of strings

Comment: You changed the `==` in the wrong place in the `if` statement...

Comment: `Error: /Users/nah/Desktop/studentList.java:137: operator < cannot be applied to int,<nulltype>`

Comment: Are you sure `L1` and `L2` are not `null` and that their `studentID` fields are non-null arrays?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I guess that wouldn't generate compile time error.

Comment: Please also correct this line:  `pointer == pointer + 1`

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is directly related to the same error but your line

```
 while(pointer<((L1.studentID.length)+(L2.studentId.length))){
```

has mis-spelt the second "studentId" and should be "studentID"

```
 while(pointer<((L1.studentID.length)+(L2.studentID.length))){
```

that is of course unless you happen to have two arrays defined for your studentID class, each with a different case.

I also agree with the other answers related to the "==" comparison operator, but you're telling us the error is related to the `while` statement

Comment: Though wouldn't that throw a different error? Before it even got to this?

Answer (score 1):

The only error I can see is:

```
if(C[pointer] = C[pointer+1]){
```

this should be:

```
if(C[pointer] == C[pointer+1]){
```

Comment: So, what's the relation with operator < then?

Answer (score 0):

The following will not work in Java:

```
if (C[pointer] = C[pointer+1])
```

This is assignment, its type is int, it cannot be used in the if statement

Comment: @iamnotmaynard this code will work only if C is array of boolean (or Boolean), but in the question it is array of int. This code will not compile in Java. In C/C++ it will, but not in Java.

Answer (score 0):

While loop ? Ok. Debugging is done by simplifying expressions.

The only thing where we see < is the loop condition. Instead of

```
  int pointer = 0;
  while(pointer<((L1.studentID.length)+(L2.studentId.length))){
```

do

```
  int pointer = 0;
  int len = ((L1.studentID.length)+(L2.studentId.length));
  while(pointer< len){
```

If error again, simplify the error-raising expression.

I think that this question is mistitled. It is **** ambigous only because you do not attempt to localize it. Post a question only if "<" does not work for two integers. The current question title must be: "how do you debug Java programs?"